# TS2339: Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm converting a js file to ts in WebStorm 2016.2.2.

I had the following snippet:

```
///<reference path="./typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />

global.base_dir = __dirname;

global.abs_path = function(path) {
    return global.base_dir + path;
};
global.include = function(file) {
    return require(global.abs_path('/' + file));
};
```

`base_dir`, `abs_path` and `include` produced the errors:

> TS2339: Property 'base_dir' does not exist on type 'Global'
>
> TS2339: Property 'abs_path' does not exist on type 'Global'
>
> TS2339: Property 'include' does not exist on type 'Global'

So I added them to 'Global' interface as following:

```
///<reference path="./typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />

declare namespace NodeJS{
    interface Global {
        base_dir: string;
        abs_path: (path: string) => string;
        include: (file: string) => string;
    }
}

global.base_dir = __dirname;

global.abs_path = function(path) {
    return global.base_dir + path;
};
global.include = function(file) {
    return require(global.abs_path('/' + file));
};
```

It did eliminate those errors.

Then, I continued converting the rest of the file, I had to import both `Request` and `Response` from express, so I added the following:

```
///<reference path="./typings/modules/express/index.d.ts" />

import {Request, Response} from "~express/lib/express";
```

So now the whole snippet is like that:

```
///<reference path="./typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />
///<reference path="./typings/modules/express/index.d.ts" />

import {Request, Response} from "~express/lib/express";

declare namespace NodeJS{
    interface Global {
        base_dir: string;
        abs_path: (path: string) => string;
        include: (file: string) => string;
    }
}

global.base_dir = __dirname;

global.abs_path = function(path) {
    return global.base_dir + path;
};
global.include = function(file) {
    return require(global.abs_path('/' + file));
};
```

Unfortunately, adding the `import` statement has returned the TS2339 error, so I stuck again with:

> TS2339: Property 'base_dir' does not exist on type 'Global'
>
> TS2339: Property 'abs_path' does not exist on type 'Global'
>
> TS2339: Property 'include' does not exist on type 'Global'

BTW Express has nothing to to with this error specifically. I've tried to import from other modules and it produced the same error. It occurs when I have at least one `import` statement

Does someone know how can I fix it?

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1574

Comment: @lena thanks, It's exactly my issue and it's detailed very clearly in this link. You can write it as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you so much as always!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that any typescript file with top-level import or export becomes a module. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1574