# cant deploy because of Property 'category' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, deployment, production

Hi everything is working fine, I am able to add and remove products and it looks like they all have the properties I added to them in the db.  Unfortunately I am prevented from deploying for production because I am getting errors.

```
ERROR in src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(10,11): : Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(27,13): : Property 'price' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(48,11): : Property 'category' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(66,11): : Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(10,11): : Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(27,13): : Property 'price' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(48,11): : Property 'category' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(66,11): : Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

So this means that these properties are not found on the object 'product'?

Yet every single one of my products in the db has these properties.

So why am I getting this error?

component:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../category.service';
import { ProductService } from '../../product.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  product = {};
  id;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getAll();

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (this.id) {
      this.productService
        .get(this.id)
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(p => (this.product = p));
    }
  }

  save(product) {
    if (this.id) {
      this.productService.update(this.id, product);
    } else {
      this.productService.create(product);
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }

  delete() {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      return;
    }
    this.productService.delete(this.id);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <form #f="ngForm"
            (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input #title="ngModel"
                    [(ngModel)]="product.title"
                    name="title"
                    tobject
                    ;product
                    'ype="text"
                    id="title"
                    class="form-control"
                    required>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"
                    *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">Title is required.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                    </div>
                    <input #price="ngModel"
                        [(ngModel)]="product.price"
                        name="price"
                        type="number"
                        class="form-control"
                        aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"
                        required
                        [min]="0">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"
                    *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
                    <div *ngIf="price.errors.required">Price is required.</div>
                    <div *ngIf="price.errors.min">Price must be equal to or greater than zero.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select #category="ngModel"
                    [(ngModel)]="product.category"
                    name="category"
                    id="category"
                    class="form-control"
                    required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async"
                        [value]="c.$key">
                        {{ c.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"
                    *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">Category is required.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imageUrl">Image URL</label>
                <input #imageUrl="ngModel"
                    [(ngModel)]="product.imageUrl"
                    name="imageUrl"
                    type="text"
                    id="imageUrl"
                    class="form-control"
                    required
                    url>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"
                    *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid">
                    <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">Image URL is required.</div>
                    <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url">Image URL must be formatted correctly.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger"
                (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <product-card [product]="product"
            [show-actions]="false"></product-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

product variable is defined here:

```
export interface Product {
  $key: string;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}
```

Ive checked a few other posts like this one: [TS2339: Property does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068806/ts2339-property-does-not-exist-on-type)

... but they have slightly different problems

Comment: Where is your product variable defined? That's the TS code for the products form component that you should show. The error is probably because your product variable is not strongly typed

Comment: Good suggestion, I added the product interface at the bottom.

Comment: Think you provided us the wrong component, errors state that there an error in `product-form.component.html`, so I would assume you have `ProductFormComponent`? The one you posted is `ProductsComponent` with template pointing to `'./products.component.html'`

Comment: ....wow that did it.

Comment: Now that you provided the correct component, error is this line `product = {};` Provide a type for it like `product: Product = {};`

Comment: what a dumb mistake.. was looking at the wrong component the whole time. thank you sir

Comment: so this fixes the whole not being able to deploy thing but then it breaks   TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined     guess thats why I declared it as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring with type any will solve it.

```
product:any={};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare field `product` with type and not define it: `product: Product;`